# Will Rhizopus Oligosporus Mold Die When Frozen?

Tags: fermenter, safety

Will Rhizopus Oligosporus Mold Die When Frozen?

I'm looking to start a Tempeh business. I know that Gunther Pfaff (Betsy's Tempeh) used to pasteurize their tempeh at 180ºF to kill the Rhizopus Oligosporus mold and spores before packaging. I'm wondering if freezing my freshly made, vacuum packed tempeh prior to sale will have the same effect. I don't like the idea of partially cooking my tempeh prior to selling it. If I must however that is what I'll do.

Thanks, steffan Heydon

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not pertain to homebrewing.

Answer (score 1):

The best tempeh is fresh tempeh although it has no shelf life (about 3 days)making it difficult to maintain a business the next best tempeh is frozen, after the tempeh is finished fermenting it should be frozen right away at -5 degrees in a freezer. I’ve been making tempeh commercially for 15 years glad to answer any questions